# Using highlighting and middle click for copy/paste in RStudio

Tags: rstudio

In linux I frequently highlight text with the mouse to copy, and middle click somewhere else to paste. In RStudio, this does not work, forcing the use of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or right-click menus. I often want to quickly copy segments of text between the console, editor, and browsers. Is there a way to get highlight+middleclick working?

Comment: Issue on github: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1667

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been [noted by the RStudio developers](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200656357-Copy-paste-with-middle-mouse-button-on-Linux) and added to their list. Unfortunately, that was five years ago, so don't hold your breath...

There are a lot of [alternatives to RStudio](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5345/ide-alternatives-for-r-programming-rstudio-intellij-idea-eclipse-visual-stud). I haven't tried them all but RKward supports middle clicks.